# my waiting list only assign to one booth but I have to assign to all 6 booths (in java)

Tags: java

As you can see in the screenshots, when I remove one patient from booth 2 it doesn't assign the waiting list patient.

I known in my code the problem is in `public static void remove(String booth[],String waiting[][])` the case is I don't known how fix.

If it is possible please help me

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class menu{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        String decision = "";
        String[] booth = new String[6];
        String[][] waiting = new String[152][6];

        for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++ ){
            booth[x] = "empty";
        }

        for (int y = 0; y < 151; y++ ){
            for (int z = 0; z < 6; z++ ){
                waiting[y][z] = "empty";
            }
        }


        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("100 or VVB: View all Vaccination Booths \n101 or VEB: View all Empty Booths\n102 or APB: Add Patient to a Booth\n103 or RPB: Remove Patient from a Booth\n104 or VPS: View Patients Sorted in alphabetical order\n105 or SPD: Store Program Data into file\n106 or LPD: Load Program Data from file\n107 or VRV: View Remaining Vaccinations\n108 or AVS: Add Vaccinations to the Stock\n999 or EXT: Exit the Program ");
        System.out.println("Enter number code or letter code");

        decision = input.nextLine();
        

        while(!decision.equals("999")||!decision.equals("EXT")){


        if (decision.equals("100") || decision.equals("VVB")){
            viewall(booth);

        }else if (decision.equals("101") || decision.equals("VEB")){
            empty(booth);

        }else if (decision.equals("102") ||decision.equals("APB")){
            add(booth,waiting);

        }else if (decision.equals("103") || decision.equals(" RPB")){
            remove(booth,waiting);

        }else if (decision.equals("104") || decision.equals(" VPS")){
            Sorted(booth);

        }else if (decision.equals("105") || decision.equals("SPD")){
            store(booth);

        }else if (decision.equals("106") || decision.equals("LPD")){
            load(booth);

        }else if (decision.equals("107") || decision.equals("VRV")){


        }else if (decision.equals("108") || decision.equals(" AVS")){


        }else if (decision.equals("999") || decision.equals("EXT")){
            System.out.println("Exit program ...............");
            break;

        }else {
            System.out.println("please enter the right number code or letter code");

        }System.out.println("Enter number code or letter code");

        decision = input.nextLine();
        }


    }


    public static void viewall(String booth[]){
        int x = 0 ;
        while(x<6){
            System.out.println("booth" + x + " is occupied by "+ booth[x]);
            x++;
            }
        }

    public static void empty(String booth[]){
        int x = 0;
        while(x<6){
            if(booth[x].equals("empty")){
                System.out.println("booth no " + x + " is empty");
            }
        x++;
        }

    }

    public static void add(String booth[], String waiting[][]){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int waitingnum = 0;
        int boothnum = 0;
        String aa = ""  ;
        String bb = ""  ;
        String cc = ""  ;
        String dd = ""  ;
        String ee = ""  ;
        String ff = "  ";
        String vacination = "";

        while (boothnum < 6){
            System.out.println("Enter booth number between (0-5) else type any number to exit \nbooth 0-1 vacination type AstraZeneca\nbooth 2-3 vacination type Snopharm\nbooth 4-5 vacination type Pfizer\nelse type any number to exit ");
            boothnum = input.nextInt();

            if(boothnum == 0 ||boothnum == 1){
                vacination = "AstraZeneca";
            }else if(boothnum == 2 ||boothnum == 3){
                vacination = "Snopharm";
            }else{
                vacination = "Pfizer";
            }

            if (boothnum < 6){

                if(booth[boothnum].equals("empty")){
                    input.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("enter first name of booth no."+ boothnum +" of Patient");
                    aa = input.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("enter second name of booth no."+ boothnum +" of Patient");
                    bb = input.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("enter age of booth no."+ boothnum +" of Patient");
                    cc = input.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("enter city of booth no."+ boothnum +" of Patient");
                    dd = input.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("enter NIC or Passport of booth no."+ boothnum +" of Patient");
                    ee = input.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("vaccination type is "+ vacination +" for Patient");

                    booth[boothnum] = aa + ff + bb + ff + cc + ff + dd + ff + ee + ff + vacination;

                }else if(!booth[boothnum].equals("empty")){
                    System.out.println("you will be tansfered to the waiting list");

                    input.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("enter first name of waiting list no."+ boothnum +" of Patient");
                    aa = input.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("enter second name of waiting list no."+ boothnum +" of Patient");
                    bb = input.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("enter age of waiting list no."+ boothnum +" of Patient");
                    cc = input.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("enter city of waiting list no."+ boothnum +" of Patient");
                    dd = input.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("enter NIC or Passport of waiting list no."+ boothnum +" of Patient");
                    ee = input.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("vaccination type is "+ vacination +" for Patient");

                    waiting[waitingnum][boothnum] = aa + ff + bb + ff + cc + ff + dd + ff + ee + ff + vacination;
                    waitingnum++;

                }
            }
                System.out.println("process finished");
        }

   }

    public static void remove(String booth[],String waiting[][]){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int waitingnum = 0;
        int deletenum = 0;

            while(deletenum<6){
                
                if(deletenum<6){

                    System.out.println("Type the boot number(0-5) you want to delete the customer from or any other number to cancel:");

                    deletenum= input.nextInt();{

                        if(deletenum<6){

                            if (booth[deletenum].equals("empty")){

                                System.out.println("booth no " + deletenum + " is already empty");
                                }else {

                                    booth[deletenum]=waiting[waitingnum][deletenum];

                                    for (int x = 0; x<151 ; x++){

                                    waiting[waitingnum + x][deletenum]=waiting[waitingnum + (x + 1)][deletenum];

                                    }

                                    System.out.println("Successfully deleted customer from booth no. " + deletenum+ " and added from waiting list");
                                }
                        }else {System.out.println("process finished");}
                    }

            }

        }
    }   

    public static void Sorted(String booth[]){

    }



    public static void store(String booth[]){
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int boothnum = 0;

        try{
            FileWriter in= new FileWriter("store.txt");

            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++ )

            in.write("booth num " + x + " is occupied by "+ booth[x] + "\n");

            in.close();

            System.out.println("Successfully written into text file");
        }
            catch(Exception e){

            System.out.println("Error writing into text");
                        
            }

    }

    
    public static void load(String booth[]){

        File file = new File("D:/campus/2nd SEM/010/seperate/store.txt");
        try{
            Scanner line = new Scanner(file);

            while(line.hasNextLine()){
                System.out.println(line.nextLine());
        }
            }
            catch(Exception e){

            System.out.println("Error writing into text");
                        
            }

    }   



}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please read about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The keyword here being *minimal*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think why you are not able to empty things is because you don't actually make them empty. Following is changed function; change is in the loop for `for (int x = 0; x<151 ; x++){`. But I think the root problem  might be different.

I do not really understand why waiting is declared as `waiting[151][6]`. I would have thought it would make sense to have it declared as `waiting[6][151]` assuming each booth has waiting list.

```
    public static void remove(String booth[],String waiting[][]){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int waitingnum = 0;
    int deletenum = 0;

        while(deletenum<6){
            
            if(deletenum<6){

                System.out.println("Type the boot number(0-5) you want to delete the customer from or any other number to cancel:");

                deletenum= input.nextInt();{

                    if(deletenum<6){

                        if (booth[deletenum].equals("empty")){

                            System.out.println("booth no " + deletenum + " is already empty");
                            }else {

                                booth[deletenum]=waiting[waitingnum][deletenum];

                                for (int x = 0; x<151 ; x++){

                                waiting[waitingnum + x][deletenum]=waiting[waitingnum + (x + 1)][deletenum];
                                    if (149 == x) {
                                        waiting[waitingnum + (x + 1)][deletenum] = "empty";
                                        String[] row = waiting[waitingnum + (x + 1)];
                                        System.out.println(row);
                                        //break;
                                    }

                                }

                                System.out.println("Successfully deleted customer from booth no. " + deletenum+ " and added from waiting list");
                            }
                    }else {System.out.println("process finished");}
                }

        }

    }
}
```